# Create dynamic textual high DPI images with PHP

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, gd, image-manipulation

I currently use **PHP GD Library**.

My goal is to to create textual images for printing stamps with 600DPI.

In order to do that, and due to the limitation of GD Library, I tried to factorize the sizes of width, height and font and then resize it. Unfortunately that did not help.

Is it possible to set the DPI of generated images in GD library?
If not, are there any alternatives?

If not possible in PHP, please refer me to something else.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what sort of things you are trying to create exactly, but you may have some luck with ImageMagick which is free and installed on most Linux distros, and available for OSX and Windows too.

You can maybe have a play around at the command-line with commands like this, to see if it can meet your needs, then convert to PHP, Perl, Ruby or any other languages for which ImageMagick has bindings.

```
convert -density 600 -units pixelsperinch                     \
        -size 2500x2000 gradient:red-blue                     \
        -pointsize 14 -font Trattatello                       \
        -gravity southeast                                    \
        -fill black -stroke white -strokewidth 2              \
        -draw "text 25,25 'Go ImageMagick'" image.jpg
```

[image]

Check what we have created with `identify`:

```
  identify -verbose  image.jpg
```

**Output**

```
  Format: JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format)
  Mime type: image/jpeg
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 2500x2000+0+0
  Resolution: 600x600
  Print size: 4.16667x3.33333
  Units: PixelsPerInch
  Type: TrueColor
  ...
  ...
```

You can also use `Pango` or Postscript if you have more complicated layout needs. There are many examples [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#text_operators).